# Write the function $\frac{1}{(z+1)(3-z)}$ as a Laurent series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z+1)(3-z)}=\frac{1}{4z+4} + \frac{1}{12-4z}$$

$$\frac{1}{4z+4}=\frac{1}{4z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{-1}{z}}=\frac{1}{4z}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{-1}{z}\right)^k$$

$$\frac{1}{12-4z}=\frac{1}{12}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{3}}=\frac{1}{12}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{3}\right)^k$$

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{4z}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{-1}{z}\right)^k+\frac{1}{12}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{3}\right)^k$$

I can rewrite that as $$f(z)=\frac{1}{4z}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{0} (-1)^k z^k+\frac{1}{12}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k z^k$$.

I need to move the $\frac{1}{4z}$ and $\frac{1}{12}$ into the sums but finding a series that will converge to each, but I have no idea what to use for either. Any suggestions? Am I taking a wrong approach or is there an obvious series to use for this?

Edit: The center is $0$ and the region in $1 \le |z| \le 3$.

I think I can use a geometric sequence to say $\frac{1}{4z}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2})^{k-1}\frac{z}{k}$ and $\frac{1}{12}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{36}(\frac{2}{9})^{k-1}\frac{z}{k}$. I'm pretty sure that's true, but it seems like it makes the whole thing a complicated mess.

Comment: What is the region of convergence ?

Comment: @Winther That becomes $f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{4} (-z)^{k-1} +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{12}(\frac{z}{3})^{k-1}$ ?

Comment: My comment was to the previous version of the question where the point and region was not specified. With the new edit that is indeed the result you are after. The first series converge for $|z| \geq 1$ and the second for $|z| \leq 3$ giving convergence of the sum in the desired region $1\leq |z| \leq 3$.

Comment: @ winther I was told my result is supposed to look like $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_kz^k +z^k$ with $a_k$ equal to one series for negative n values and another for positive n values. So I say $a_k=\frac{1}{4}(-1)^k for -\infty \le n \le 0$ and $a_k=\frac{1}{12}(\frac{1}{3})^k for 0 \le n \le \infty$ ? Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Though I would double-check the calculation, you seem to have some small index errors. I get $a_k = \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4}$ for $-\infty < k \leq -1$ and $a_k = \frac{1}{12\cdot 3^k}$ for $k\geq 0$.

Comment: @Winther The thing I'm still not clear on is how I take the first sum $\sum_{k=0}^{-\infty} \frac{1}{4} (-1)^k z^k$ and rewrite it as a sum from negative infinity to zero. I would think it becomes $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{4} (-1)^{-k} z^{-k}$. I'm pretty sure that's algebraically true, but then that doesn't fit how my solution is supposed to look.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{4(z+1)} = \frac{1}{4z(1+z^{-1})}$ so the first sum is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{4z^{k+1}}$ (you seem to  have forgotten the extra factor of $z$). Now if you want to change it to a sum from $-\infty$ to $0$ to get it on the standard form $f(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k z^k$ you can take $n = -k$ so it becomes $\sum_{n=0,-1,-2,\ldots} \frac{(-1)^{-n}}{4}z^{n-1}$. Then you can shift to $m = n-1$ to get $\sum_{m=-1,-2,-3,\ldots} \frac{(-1)^{-1-m}}{4}z^m$. And $(-1)^{-m} = (-1)^m$ so you can also write it as $\sum_{m=-1,-2,-3,\ldots} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{4}z^m$.

Answer (score 2):

> The function
>
> \begin{align*}
>  f(z)&=\frac{1}{(z+1)(3-z)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4(z+1)}-\frac{1}{4(z-3)}
> \end{align*}
>    has two simple poles at $-1$ and $3$.

Since we want to find a Laurent expansion with center $0$, we look at the poles $-1$ and $3$ and see they determine *three* regions.

\begin{align*}
 |z|<1,\qquad\quad
 1<|z|<3,\qquad\quad
 3<|z|
 \end{align*}

- The first region $ |z|<1$ is a disc with center $0$, radius $1$ and the pole $-1$ at the boundary of the disc. In the *interior* of this disc all two fractions with poles $-1$ and $3$  admit a representation as *power series* at $z=0$.
- The second region $1<|z|<3$ is the annulus with center $0$, inner radius $1$ and outer radius $3$. Here we have a representation of the fraction with poles $-1$ as principal part of a Laurent series at $z=0$, while the fraction with pole at $3$ admits a representation as power series.
- The third region $|z|>3$ containing all points outside the disc with center $0$ and radius $3$ admits for all fractions a representation as principal part of a Laurent series at $z=0$.

A power series expansion of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=0$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}&=\frac{1}{a}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{a}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{n+1}}(-z)^n
\end{align*}
The principal part of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=0$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}&=\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{z}}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{(-z)^n}
=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{(-z)^{n+1}}\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n-1}}{(-z)^n}
\end{align*}

> We can now obtain the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ for all three regions.
>
> - *Region 2:* $1<|z|<3$
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(z)&=\frac{1}{4(z+1)}-\frac{1}{4(z-3)}\\
> &=-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(-z)^n}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(-3)^{n+1}}(-z)^n\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{z^n}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{n+1}}z^n\\
> \end{align*}

The Laurent expansion for the other regions can be calculated similarly.

Comment: This is good, very well explained! (+1)

Comment: @YujieZha: Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can write the expression as:
$$\frac{1}{(z+1)(-z+3)} = \frac{-1}{(z+1)(z-3)}$$

Use partial fractions:
$$\frac{-1}{(z+1)(z-3)} = \frac{A}{z+1}+\frac{B}{z-3}$$
$$-1 = A(z-3)+B(z+1)$$
If z=3, then
$$-1 = B(3+1)$$
$$-1 = B(4)$$
$$B=\frac{-1}{4}$$

If z=1, then 
$$-1 = A(1-3)$$
$$-1 = A(-2)$$
$$1 = A(2)$$
$$A = 1/2$$

So, we have:
$$\frac{-1}{(z+1)(z-3)} = (\frac{1}{2})\frac{1}{z+1}+(\frac{-1}{4})\frac{1}{z-3}$$

The previous expression is a Laurent Series. Because the expression has no expressions of the form
$$\frac{1}{z^{n}}$$
The Laurent Series behaves as a Taylor Series.

If we suppose that in z=0 the expression is not analytic, then we can write it as

$$\frac{-1}{(z+1)(z-3)} = (\frac{1}{2})\frac{1}{z(1+\frac{1}{z})}+(\frac{-1}{4})\frac{1}{z(1-\frac{3}{z})}$$